# Right click of a button in a website in C# using puppeteersharp

Tags: c#, right-click, puppeteer-sharp

Need to perform right click of a button in a website in C# using puppeteersharp. Tried the below code but it is not working:

`await page.ClickAsync({ button: 'right'}"[class*='_16aPYHYIOVxzNYTA4BGnwS NJVykX0WljoRws2qTYI5G _3FwRpWCSns-2PgbiDhEErG']");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ClickOptions` argument:

```cs
await page.ClickAsync(
    "[class*='_16aPYHYIOVxzNYTA4BGnwS NJVykX0WljoRws2qTYI5G _3FwRpWCSns-2PgbiDhEErG']", 
    new ClickOptions() { Button = MouseButton.Right } );
```